# COBOL Replace the first line in a file without using OPEN I-O and REWRITE

Tags: file, cobol, microfocus

Say that I have a file with the below format

```
<records count="n">
record line 1
record line 2
.
.
.
record line n
</records>
```

I'll have to open this file and change the value of n to another value based on some logic. After change my file should look like.

```
<records count="m">
record line 1
record line 2
.
.
.
record line n
</records>
```

I can open the file in OPEN I-O mode and change the first line using the REWRITE option to replace the first line. But I don't want to use these methods. Is there a way to achieve the same logic using OPEN INPUT and OPEN OUTPUT mode and replace the line with WRITE method.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve the same logic using OPEN INPUT and OPEN
>   OUTPUT mode and replace the line with WRITE method[?]

No, that would leave you with only the `<records count="m">` in the file. All other records would be lost!

As long as the length of the first record is the same, after changing `n` to `m`, `REWRITE` is the most straight forward way to update that record.

Perhaps, if you explain why you want to use `WRITE`, there may be something else that could be done.

---

If the file is not 'too' large, read all the records into memory, change the first record, then write all the records to the file.

If the file is 'too' large, copy the file changing the first record, delete the first file, then rename the copy.

Perhaps less efficient for 'too' large, sort the file by adding a sequence number and changing the first record. This simply uses the sort file to hold the data, temporarily. Possibly a poor choice for a program to be converted.

You need to define what the limit for 'too' is.

There are non-standard routines for file access in Micro Focus, but those might be more difficult to convert.

Comment: I'm converting this COBOL program to Java. But the Java API for File processing is restricted to use open output and input and do not have a method for open i-o. Also the API does not have method for rewrite.

Comment: Thats the reason why converting COBOL to Java is maybe not the best idea ever .... anyway: In this case you sould ask not how to do it in COBOL, but in Java ...

Comment: Thank you @RickSmith Can you provide me the code to copy content of one file to another please. That'll be really helpful.

Comment: @Vishnu I put a COBOL 85 standard conforming program at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/File_input/output#COBOL_85 . This will need to be modified, of course.